# Creating a Favorites list with shareable url using node an mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, database

I've been searching a ton and maybe I'm using the wrong search terms, but essentially I want to have a user select items to add to a favorites list and then create a unique url they can share. An example can be found at http://www.sortfolio.com

When you click the "shortlist?" button at the bottom of an item it'll get added to the "My Shortlist (Your Favorites)" and when you click there it'll show what you've added to your favorites list and provide a shareable unique url with your favorites.

I have a MongoDB database and using Node with Express. I'm assuming you'd collect the items database id's and then make a get call to grab them, but how would I then create the unique shareable url. I think sortfolio is built with Ruby on Rails which I am not using. If anyone can point me in the right direction to replicate this type of functionality it would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi just like you said you've to create one another Mongodb collection like favorites 
{
favouriteid:unique id/if you want short uid the u can us npm uid, 
Item:ref to production product collection
}

Then  create an api for getting favorites according to favorites.

And in given site example user can shortlist and share item without login also. So in this case on Frontend side store shortlist in product in sessionstorage and if user want to see favorite list then add new favorite record with items fetching from sessionstorage or locals to rage.  Provide sharable url which have unique sharable I'd. Above thing manage according to cookie basic.